# JQuery Mobile: select menu refresh true does not work on iOS

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

I am using this wonderful piece of code:

```
function rebuildFilterDialogConditions(filterPopup, jsonArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.filters.length; i++) {
        var filterSelect = $('select#' + jsonArray.filters[i].filterCode);
        var filterOptionsSelect = $('select#' + jsonArray.filters[i].filterCode + ' option');
        filterOptionsSelect.remove();
        filterSelect.append('<option value="default" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">' + jsonArray.filters[i].filterName + '</option>');

        for (var j = 0; j < jsonArray.filters[i].filterValues.length; j++) {
            filterSelect.append('<option value="' + jsonArray.filters[i].filterValues[j] + '">' + jsonArray.filters[i].filterValues[j] + '</option>');
        }
        filterSelect.selectmenu('refresh', true);
    }
}
```

Technically it removes every `option` of the `select`, replaces it with new data, then calls `selectmenu('refresh', true)` to force it to rebuild.

This works on Android.

This does NOT WORK on iOS. Does not work meaning that it doesn't refresh the "native-looking" menu in the bottom, it stays the exact same as before.

Same code, of course.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was completely elsewhere, this didn't even run as indicated by actual debugging on iOS.

The method:

```
    filterSelect.change(function() {
        ...
        bridge.callHandler("updateResultSearchFilters", result);
    });
```

did not have a reference to `bridge`, so the method was never actually called...